# Making and exporting custom split normals?

Tags: modeling, edges, normals

i imported this model and some of the edges are shaded smooth even thought they are split. I know it's because it has custom split normals but i don't know how i would go about making my own model like that within blender and then exporting it

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please add a descriptive title that reflects the content of your question